# Requests to remove community wiki

Tags: support, community-wiki

In the old days of MathOverflow, community wiki status was irreversible. This is no longer the case! There are many old questions and answers that became community wiki by accident or other reasons. For example, I had turned my first MathOverflow answer community wiki just to see what the button did.

Post requests for removal of community wiki status here. You can get a list of all your community wiki posts with [this data query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/138942/community-wiki-posts-by-user).

PS: Removing community wiki status is not an edit, so don't worry about bumping old questions.

Comment: You read my mind, because I was about to request CW-removal for [When does $ZFC \vdash\ ' ZFC \vdash \varphi\ '$ imply $ZFC \vdash \varphi$?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/127322/6085), but I see you already removed it there.

Comment: Would this have a retroactive effect on reputation?

Comment: In theory but only after a recalc, which are not all that frequent, I think.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger One can trigger a reputation recalculation, by going to http://mathoverflow.net/reputation, scrolling to the bottom, and clicking the button there.

Comment: (Thank you, @FrançoisG.Dorais for the prompt response.)

Comment: Recalcs are no longer necessary, rep is basically real time on SE 2.0 :) If the status is removed, any rep change should take an almost (within the minute) immediate effect.

Comment: Is this intended for all requests, or only ones from MO 1.0?  Is flagging a good way to make such requests?

Comment: @Jonas: Yes, flagging is a good way to make such requests.

Comment: (I upvoted one of the answers so Community won't bump it ever again!)

Comment: @Tim Post: I don’t believe this. Around October 11, my reputation suddenly went *up* by 40 or so points in the blink of an eye, whereas according to the reputation tab, I was supposed to *lose* 50 points due to a deletion of a user at that point. After seeing this thread, the only explanation I have for that mysterious behaviour is that the deletion of the user triggered a recalc of my reputation, which retroactively added points for an answer to the question mentioned above by Andres Caicedo, de-CWed on September 24.

Answer (score 2):

**[DONE]** Please remove CW from [Solutions to the Continuum Hypothesis](https://mathoverflow.net/q/23829/6085).

It is a nice question (even though its wording could use some tweaking), and has received some excellent answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few requests to remove CW in the comments of: [The conditions in the definition of Brownian motion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43015/the-conditions-in-the-definition-of-brownian-motion) which was bumped recently.

Answer (score 1):

**[DONE]** Please remove CW from [A recommended roadmap into inner models](https://mathoverflow.net/q/73075/6085).

And noise to avoid this being turned into a comment.

Comment: @François, thanks for that. I have always regretted on posting that as wiki.

Answer (score 0):

**[DONE]** Please remove CW from [A question about Transfinite Induction](https://mathoverflow.net/q/46573/6085).

And noise to avoid this being turned into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**[DONE]** Please remove CW from

> [Bourbaki's epsilon-calculus notation](https://mathoverflow.net/q/14356/6085).

And noise $\&$c $\&$c.

Answer (score 0):

**[DONE]** Please remove CW from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/25835/6085) to

> [A simple infinite dimensional optimization problem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/25800/6085).

And noise, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two more, both in the same answer to avoid cluttering:

- [Is there a “classical” proof of this $j$-value congruence?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/45638/6085)
- **[DONE]** [Bounding the modular discriminant of an elliptic curve in the j-invariant](https://mathoverflow.net/q/48544/6085)

Comment: It seems the first question was intentionally made CW by the author, and I don't want to override that decision.

Comment: I removed CW from Noam's answer, but left it on the question since that is probably the author's wish.

Comment: I also removed CW from the other question's answers.

Answer (score 0):

**[DONE]** perhaps this [old answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/111294/11260) can be un-CW-ed? (9 revisions triggered the CW status on MO 1.0)

thanks!

Comment: Okay, it's undone.

Answer (score -1):

**[DONE]** I ask for removing CW from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136273/origin-and-first-uses-of-ell-p-norms/136339#136339) to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136273/origin-and-first-uses-of-ell-p-norms). It was a misunderstanding on my part at that time.