# Frequent revisions leading to a community wiki

Tags: support, community-wiki

Due to frequent revisions my answer has become a community wiki, can I undo this.

> Also now if a bounty gets awarded to my answer will I get the points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can flag and request that a moderator remove community wiki status.  (This is one of the new features since the switch to MO 2.0.  [Here's a related post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/871/requests-to-remove-community-wiki) about the removal of CW, but it appears to focus on posts from before the migration.)

Yes, bounty points are still awarded for community wiki answers.

Comment: I don't think the link is for that. I think it's for questions from the MO 1.0 period.

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks, I interpreted it as more general, but may be wrong.  I'll reword.

Answer (score 6):

Bounties are still earned.

To your first question, you can flag for moderators to reverse that. Note however that they may decide not to do so, if they feel that your frequent editing was unjustified - or for any other reason.